# NSURLCONNECTION didReceiveData: storing NSDATA in NSMutableData error

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm calling a web service using NsUrlConnection which is returning a lot of data. this is calling the didReceiveData method many times and NSLog shows the data is correct when I print it out.

The problem I'm having however is now related to storing the returned NSData in the didReceiveData method to an NSMutableData ivar for later use.

I found an example of it's use at http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/8/8b/URL_Connection_example.txt and with a few modifications I've gotten to the following below:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData;
```

.m

```
@synthesize receivedData;


-(Boolean) getCategories {

MCUtility * util = [MCUtility alloc];
NSString * strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [util getCategoryUrl]];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strUrl]);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection == nil) {
    return FALSE;
} else {    
   self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    [receivedData setLength:0]; //<<OK call
}

return TRUE;

}

#pragma NSURLCONNECTION

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
// This method is called when the server has determined that it
// has enough information to create the NSURLResponse object.

// It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a
// redirect, so each time we reset the data.

// receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
if (receivedData != nil)
    [receivedData setLength:0]; //<< thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 2, address....)
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
NSLog(@"Data Received");
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]]);
[receivedData appendData:data];  //<< (2) thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 2, address....)
```

In the setup method getCategories I create the initial NSMutableData variable using

```
self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
```

( (1) After this I've added a test call to [receivedData setLength:0]; which isn't actually part of the code but it works ok here)

the call to the web service is fine so I start receiving the data in didReceiveData.

In the method didReceiveResponse the example states a call to [receivedData setLength:0]; is required. At this point now I get a

```
thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 2, address....)
```

..I didnt' get this error just after I created the iVar object previously as I stated at (1)

In the method didReceiveData I'm also getting this error when I try to assign the data to the NSMutableData at (2).

So being a bit of a objective c newbie I'm thinking this has something to do with the iVar I'm using to store the data. Is there anything simple and obvious being missed?

Comment: Change your property from `assign` to `strong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`receivedData` is being released.

`[NSMutableData data]` returns an autoreleased variable.  You need to retain it or change your property definition to retain it.

`@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;` should work.

If using ARC, make the property to be

`@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData *receivedData;`